# Can a group be a union of three subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am being asked to show an example of when this fails or prove it rigorously.  I am thinking of using an example to disprove the claim that a group can be a union of three subgroups.  However I am not so sure if proving it rigorously might be a better way.  What do you guys think?

Comment: Give an example of a small group that is the union of three proper subgroups.

Comment: Okay so there is no group that exists then.  Would the Klein V group work?

Comment: The Klein V group can be expressed as the union of three of its subgroups. It shouldn't be too hard for you to find this expression, especially since there are only three non-trivial proper subgroups of it.

Comment: You are assuming that the three subgroups are distinct right? Otherwise this is super easy

Comment: @graydad: Is it easier if it is allowed to have only two (still proper) subgroups?

Comment: I'm assuming that the question is meant for three distinct subgroups. Otherwise for any group $G$, it is trivial that $G$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $G \cup G \cup G = G$. And should we also assume the subgroups are proper?

Comment: @graydad: I think a better way to make the question interesting would be (as Daniel Fischer implicitly suggested) that the subgroups are to be _proper_ rather than distinct. Otherwise if there is _any_ non-trival subgroup $H$ we would have $\{e\}\cup H\cup G=G$ with distinct summands.

Comment: @Henning Makholm agreed, that is nicer.

Comment: And interestingly, the group which is equal to union of three proper subgroup have an homomorphic image whic is Klein group.

Comment: Your question is phrased in a rather confusing way. Do you want a group that can not be written as the union of three proper subgroups (take a finite [say, cyclic] group of prime order), or do you want a group where this is possible (take $\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_2$), or something else entirely?

Comment: the quaternion group of order $8$ is $<i> \cup <j> \cup <k>$

Answer (score 14):

The Klein 4-group $V_4$ is the union of three proper subgroups. A group cannot be the union of two of its proper subgroups. It might be interesting to know, that research has been done on how this might generalize.

**Theorem** (Bruckheimer, Bryan and Muir) A group is the union of three proper subgroups if and only if it has a quotient isomorphic to $V_4$.

The proof appeared in the American Math. Monthly $77$, no. $1 (1970)$. The theorem seems to be proved earlier by the Italian mathematician Gaetano Scorza, *I gruppi che possono pensarsi come somma di tre loro sottogruppi*, Boll. Un. Mat. Ital. $5 (1926), 216-218$.

For 4, 5 or 6 subgroups a similar theorem is true and the Klein 4-group is for each of the cases replaced by some finite set of groups. For 7 subgroups however, it is not true: no group can be written as a union of 7 of its proper subgroups. This was proved by Tomkinson in 1997.

There is a nice overview paper by Mira Bhargava, *Groups as unions of subgroups*, The American Mathematical Monthly, $116$, no. $5, (2009)$.

Comment: Is this for infinite groups too?

Comment: Absolutely. See also http://www.maths.org.pl/krakow/algebracw/sumy_podgrup.pdf

Answer (score 1):

this may not be much help, but there is a numeric constraint which might serve as a filter (if my understanding of the question  is correct)

if the group is of finite order $g$, the subgroups $g_1,g_2,g_3$, their intersections $g_{12},g_{23},g_{31},g_{123}$ then we require:

$$
g-g_1-g_2-g_3+g_{12}+g_{23}+g_{31} - g_{123} = 0
$$
subject to the constraints of the division lattice implied by Lagrange's theorem.

the quaternion group gives:
$$
8 -4-4-4+2+2+2-2 =0
$$