# Can a group have two different subgroups of index $2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I know that subgroup of index $2$ is normal.

I am interested in knowing that is that subgroup is unique or there exist example of subgroup which can have two subgroup of index $2$?

If there is example exist , then what is condition on subgroup implies that subgroup of index $2$ is unique?

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: A short addition to the answers: If $4$ does not divide the order of the group then the group has a unique subgroup of index $2$. More generally, if the Sylow $2$-subgroup is cyclic, then the same happens.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not even unique up to isomorphism! Take, for instance, $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\times (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Good example.  Another:  the dihedral group $D_4$ of order $8$ has at least two subgroups of order $4$:  the Klein $4$-group and the subgroup consisting of the rotations.  They are also non-iso.

Answer (score 6):

It is maybe worth noticing the following. Let $G$ be a group and let $I_2(G)=\#\{H \lt G: |G:H|=2\}$, be the number of subgroups of index $2$.

**Theorem** (Crawford, Wallace, 1975) Let $G$ be a group and $n$ a non-negative integer. Then $I_2(G)=n$ if and only if $n=2^k-1$ for some non-negative integer $k$.

See *On the Number of Subgroups of Index Two-An Application of Goursat's Theorem for Groups*, R. R. Crawford and K. D. Wallace, [Mathematics Magazine Vol. 48](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2689703?Search=yes&resultItemClick=true&searchText=bruckheimer,&searchText=bryan&searchUri=%2Faction%2FdoBasicSearch%3FQuery%3Dbruckheimer%252C%2Bbryan&refreqid=search%3A4a46127748cd3cdb7fea3f06c99e5ad9&seq=3#metadata_info_tab_contents), No. 3 (May, 1975), pp. 172-174.

From this it follows that $I_2(G) \equiv 1$ or $3$ mod $6$, and in particular, $I_2(G) \neq 2$.

Another observation (see also the quoted paper): the following are equivalent.

(a) A group $G$ has a *unique* subgroup of index $2$. 
(b) $G$ *cannot* be expressed as the union of 3 different subgroups. 
(c) $G$ does not have a quotient isomorphic to Klein's group $V_4$.

Comment: Interesting results.  I’ve never seen these.

Comment: @Randall, thanks, you might also have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959886/can-a-group-be-a-union-of-three-subgroups.

Answer (score 3):

No way is it unique (generally).  The group $G=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ has three subgroups of index $2$:  $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times\{0\}$, the vice versa, and $\{(0,0), (1,1)\}$.  You can use the same idea to cook up plenty of other examples.